# CFT in momentum space

Tags: momentum, fourier-transform, conformal-field-theory

Is there a way to see the conformal symmetry in momentum space in a CFT? I mean if I can recover the conformal group in some way in momentum space.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7760) should be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The generator of special conformal transformation act, schematically, as
$$
K\sim x^2\partial_x+x\partial_x.
$$
In momentum space this becomes
$$
K\sim p\partial_p^2+p\partial_p.
$$
Since $K$ is a second order differential operator, $e^{\lambda K}$ does not act in a local, geometrical way on functions.

So while it is possible to check infinitesimal conformal invariance in momentum space by acting with the second-order differential operator, there is no simple geometric meaning to conformal invariance in momentum space.